# Generating an elliptic paraboloid level set function

Tags: matlab, image-processing

I am currently working on Image processing and want to generate an elliptic paraboloid level set function

The equation is given as follows :

```
P(x;y;x0;y0;z0;theta;ro) = xm^2 +ro*ym^2 + z0;
where,
xm = (x-x0)*cos(theta) - (y-y0)*sin(theta);
ym = (x-x0)*sin(theta) + (y-y0)*sin(theta);
```

How can I generate this kind of level set ?

The programming I did is this :

```
clc;clear all;close all;
x0 = 0;
y0 = 0;
z0 = 0;
theta = pi/4;
ro = 1;

tic
I = ones(128,128);
for i=1:128
    for j=1:128
        xm = (i-x0).*cos(theta) - (j-y0).*sin(theta);
        ym = (i-x0).*sin(theta) + (j-y0).*sin(theta);
        I(i,j) = xm^2 + ro.*(ym^2) + z0;
    end
end
toc

contour(I,'DisplayName','I');figure(gcf)
```

The contour I get is this : 
[image]

**What** I am **confused** about is this :- I know level sets are created such that outside the level set , the value should be greater than **0** and less than **0** inside the contour or vice-versa. The **zero level** contour of the level set is the place where the value is **0**.

I checked this:

```
>> min(I(:))

ans =

    2.0000

>> max(I(:))

ans =

   3.2768e+04
```

So clearly this is not a level set.

Kindly please **clarify** the following points
1. Is my equation wrong ?
2. Is my code wrong ?

Any suggestions will be helpful.

Comment: I'm trying to understand what do you mean by level. The levels of contour function are from the value of your function (I in your case), and you don't have non-positive values in the function

Comment: Level set is a mathematical tool or function to evolve contour surfaces. For example , a 2D evolving contour is embedded in a higher dimension (3D) known as level set. This level set is now evolved by mathematical equations. A cross-sectional plane can cut at any height to give the evolving contour at any time t. I hope I am clear now.

Comment: Please consider these links http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set_method and 
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Level_set